# TFS 2010 build template failing to open in designer - how to fix?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, workflow

I can open the DefaultTemplate.xaml that was installed as part of our TFS 2010 RC setup.  I created a copy of this template called ApplicationTemplate.xaml and modified it slightly, using the workflow designer in Visual Studio.

Now, I can no longer open ApplicationTemplate.xaml.  When I try, I receive many errors like the following:

```
Error 2 Assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference. Also, verify that your project and all referenced assemblies have been built. C:\Projects\tfs\Hydraulics\BuildProcessTemplates\ApplicationTemplate.xaml 1 1828 Miscellaneous Files
```

However, I can still open and edit the DefaultTemplate.xaml file without any issues.

Has anyone else come across this problem, & if so, did you manage to resolve it or did you have to recreate the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is just to shut down & re-open Visual Studio.  I did that, and all the references load and I can edit the workflow in the designer again.

I think I'm too used to Emacs; restarting my editor never occurred to me as a potential solution to it failing to open a file :-)